# How to get special price with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, opencart, journal

There is a OpenCart platform, version 1.5.6.1 with Journal theme. On latest products page I would like to show both prices regular and special, if there is special price. The regular price is shown on this way:

```
var price = $(element).find('.price').html();

        if (price != null) {
            html += '<div class="price">' + price  + '</div>';
        }
```

I tried to get special price and show it on this way, but it not worked:

```
var special_price = $(element).find('.price-new').html();

        if (special_price != null) {
            html += '<div class="price-old">' + price + '</div> <div class="price-new">' + special_price + '</div>';
        }
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check your console do you see an error

Comment: No, there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box it should work as you want.

Looking at the latest.tpl template file, the following is there:

```
<p class="price">
<?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
<?php echo $product['price']; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new" <?php echo isset($product['date_end']) && $product['date_end'] ? "data-end-date='{$product['date_end']}'" : ""; ?>><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if ($product['tax']) { ?>
          <span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $product['tax']; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
        </p>
        <?php } ?>
```

Double check your file and get back, unless I miss understood your question.

Comment: Yes, there is the same code the problem is still not working. Probably, because of a Journal theme. I'm not sure. Still investigate this problem. Thanks for your advice!